# Uploading video to old Facebook REST API

Tags: php, video, facebook

I'm having lots of issues with uploading videos.

If I try to use `https://api-video.facebook.com` I am getting a cURL host not found error, if I use `http://api-video.facebook.com` I get a message to use `https://api-video.facebook.com`

If I try to use https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=video.upload I get a 101 error code -

```
<error_msg>Invalid API key</error_msg>
```

but the API key works for everything else, statuses, comments, likes, fql for the user?

Heres what I am sending:

```
access_token=XXXX
api_key=XXXX
call_id=1279204007.6003
description=Description+of+this%3F
format=JSON
title=Title%2C+a+title
v=2.0
sig=XXX
```

I read in the post on the [FB developers forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=220361#p220361) that splitting the session key by | gives you a correct session key? Is this the same as access_token? I have tried splitting this up with no luck.

Any ideas, or even working code in PHP (!) would be most welcome! Thanks

Comment: We have the same problem.  If anyone knows an answer it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm gonna put some bounty on this and see if anyone has an answer!

Comment: What is the application type set to in facebook settings?  Are you using any php sdk's for the facebook app?

Comment: Sup Kev, I had a similar issue (to do with session keys) when we were building Youmeo and all I could find out was that the FB Video API sucks. Looking forward to hearing the solution (if there is one).

Comment: Hello Si! We gave up and used Youtube in the end.

Comment: Hi Jostster, we were using PHP SDKs provided by FB, but they didn't work at all, so we wrote a full cURL implementation. But this didn't work. The app type is "HTML5 / mobile web"

Comment: Are you using AVG?  (The AVG LinkScanner is known to interfere with some Facebook video uploads.  <a href="http://www.hwdot.com/how-to-disable-remove-uninstall-forever-linkscanner-then-reinstall-avg-80-free-without-linkscanner/"><sup>fix</sup></a>)

Comment: No, the video uploads are done on a Linux debian server without AVG.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [this](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12696) code with the FB SDK

```
require_once 'facebook.php';

$appapikey = 'xxx';
$appsecret = 'xxx';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

$session_key = 'xxx'; //this is the infinite session_key returned when asking for the offline_access extended permission

    $args = array(
          'method' => 'facebook.video.upload',
          'v' => '1.0',
          'api_key' => $appapikey,
          'call_id' => microtime(true),
          'format' => 'JSON',
          'session_key' => $session_key,
          'title'       => 'My video title',
          'description' => 'My video description'
    );

      ksort($args);
      $sig = '';
      foreach($args as $k => $v) {
        $sig .= $k . '=' . $v;
      }
      $sig .= $appsecret;
      $args['sig'] = md5($sig);

    $args["short.wmv"] = '@E:\path\to\short.wmv';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://api-video.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.video.upload';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r($data); //returned xml here
```

I also found a [bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12696) submitted today stating that video uploads have been working and not working sporatically.  It could be your code is just fine and facebook's APIs are messing up.

EDIT:

Try [the following](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56407), it seems to have worked for a few people.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this before; I am getting no response from the api-video server.

Comment: @Kevin try using the new url i just posted in my answer.